# Printing list of variables that are used in an insert in a stored proc

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am curious if there is a way to see the variable values that are being used in an insert statement in a nested stored proc I have.  So for example, the nested stored proc is calling this statement, and I would like to find an easy way to print that list out.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
[Rate1_Amt],
[Rate2_Amt],
[Rate3_Amt],
[Rate4_Amt],
[Rate5_Amt],
[Rate6_Amt],
[Rate7_Amt],
[Rate8_Amt],
[Rate9_Amt],
[Rate10_Amt]
)
VALUES
(
@rate1,
@rate2,
@rate3,
@rate4,
@rate5,
@rate6,
@rate7,
@rate8,
@rate9,
@rate10
)
```

So would like to learn of a way to print the list of the @rate# variables by modifying the stored proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this **

```
PRINT CAST(@rate1 as varchar(max))        
PRINT CAST(@rate2   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate3   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate4   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate5   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate6   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate7   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate8   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate9   as varchar(max))
PRINT CAST(@rate10  as varchar(max))


INSERT INTO MyTable
(
[Rate1_Amt],
[Rate2_Amt],
[Rate3_Amt],
[Rate4_Amt],
[Rate5_Amt],
[Rate6_Amt],
[Rate7_Amt],
[Rate8_Amt],
[Rate9_Amt],
[Rate10_Amt]
)
VALUES
(
@rate1,
@rate2,
@rate3,
@rate4,
@rate5,
@rate6,
@rate7,
@rate8,
@rate9,
@rate10
)
```